# Integration of rational functions

Tags: calculus, integration

How would you integrate a rational function like this:

$$\frac{2x+3}{x^2+2x+10}$$

Comment: With partial fractions.

Comment: @Harv B Use $\arctan$ and $\ln$

Comment: It is irreducible

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

As $x^2+2x+10=(x+1)^2+3^2,$

write $2x+3=A(x+1)+B$

Now use $\dfrac{d(\arctan x)}{dx}=?$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that:

$$\frac{2x + 3}{x^2 + 2x + 10} = \frac{2x + 2}{x^2 + 2x + 10} + \frac{ 1}{x^2 + 2x + 10} = \frac{2x + 2}{x^2 + 2x + 10} + \frac{ 1}{(x+1)^2 + 3^2}$$

Therefore,

$$\int \frac{2x + 3}{x^2 + 2x + 10} dx = \int\frac{2x + 2}{x^2 + 2x + 10}dx+ \int\frac{ 1}{(x+1)^2 + 3^2}dx$$

$$ = \ln|x^2 + 2x + 10| +  \int\frac{ 1}{(x+1)^2 + 3^2}dx $$

$$= \ln|x^2 + 2x + 10| +   \int\frac{1/9}{(\frac{x+1}{3})^2 + 1}dx $$

$$= \ln|x^2 + 2x + 10| +   \int\frac{1/9}{(\frac{x+1}{3})^2 + 1}dx$$

$$= \ln|x^2 + 2x + 10| +   \frac{1}{9}\int\frac{1}{(\frac{x+1}{3})^2 + 1}dx$$

$$= \ln|x^2 + 2x + 10| +   \frac{1}{3} \arctan(\frac{x+1}{3}) + c$$

We can safely drop the absolute value, because $x^2 + 2x + 10 > 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, obtaining:

$$\int \frac{2x + 3}{x^2 + 2x + 10} dx = \ln(x^2 + 2x + 10) +   \frac{1}{3} \arctan(\frac{x+1}{3}) + c$$

Comment: You are an absolute star. Thanks a lot mate

Comment: You are welcome. If an answer helped you, you can always give it an upvote and/or accept it so other users know your question has been solved.

Comment: @HarvB Math_QED is right. I noticed that you have not accepted an answer yet. This does not only let other users know that your question has been solved, but if another user were to use this site, they can immediately look at the most helpful answer. Additionally, it gives you +2 reputation. [Here is how to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). I strongly recommend you do this for your other questions too.

Answer (score 0):

$x^{2}+2x+10$ prime $\rightarrow$
$$I=\int\dfrac{2x+3}{x^{2}+2x+10}dx=\int \dfrac{2x+2+1}{x^{2}+2x+10}dx=\int \dfrac{2x+2}{x^{2}+2x+10}dx +\int \dfrac{1}{(x^{2}+2x+1)+9}dx=\ln (x^{2}+2x+10)+J$$
$$J=\int \dfrac{1}{(x+1)^{2}+3^{2}}dx=\int \dfrac{1}{9\left[ \left ( \dfrac{x+1}{3}\right)^{2}+1\right]}dx=\dfrac{1}{3}\int \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{3}}{\left( \dfrac{x+1}{3}\right)^{2}+1}dx=\dfrac{1}{3}\arctan \left( \dfrac{x+1}{3}\right)$$
$$I=\ln (x^{2}+2x+10)+\dfrac{1}{3}\arctan \left( \dfrac{x+1}{3}\right)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{2x+3}{x^2+2x+10} dx$$

$$= \int \frac{2x+2+1}{x^2+2x+10} dx $$

$= \int \frac{2x+2}{x^2+2x+10} dx + \int \frac{1}{x^2+2x+10}dx$

Let solve them individually,

$$\int \frac{2x+2}{x^2+2x+10} dx$$

$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} dx = \log|f(x)|$$

$$= \log |x^2 + 2x + 10| + c$$

Other part -

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2+2x+10} dx$$

Use completing the square -

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2+2x+1+9} dx$$

$$=\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2+(3)^2} dx$$

$$\int \frac 1{x^2+a^2} dx = \frac 1a tan^{-1}\frac xa + c$$

$$=\frac 13 tan^{-1}\frac {x+1}3+ c$$

Add both to get complete answer.